# Jquery check if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to uncheck a radio button if it is checked, and likewise check a radio button if it is unchecked. However, it is always saying it is checked when it isn't.

Here is my code:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

The above code always hits the first part of the if. I've also tried

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

and

```
$(this).val()
```

and

```
$(this).attr('checked') == true
```

but nothing seems to be working.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want checkboxes? This seems to go against the normal usage of a radio button.

Comment: No, because with checkboxes you can select multiple options. I want to select 0 or 1 option. This way the user is able to undo their selection if they want.

Comment: I have an example that works, scroll down to my answer

Comment: If the radio buttons are in a group, they should have this behavior without any javascript. Perhaps you are doing work you don't need?

Comment: This will never work, you're going against the design of a radio button. As soon as you click the radio, it has the state checked, and if it's checked, you're unchecking it. So no radio button will ever be checked.

Comment: @netorious Check out my hack

Comment: have you checked out my answer? are you getting any sort of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this received negative votes. The usage of a radio button is so that you can have 0 or 1 options to select from, and a checkbox list is if you need 0 or many options selected. But what if you want to undo a radio button selection for an optional question?

I solved this by creating another attribute on radio buttons called "data-checked".

Below was the implementation:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
    var radioButton = $(this);
    var radioButtonIsChecked = radioButton.attr('data-checked') == 'true';

    // set 'checked' to the opposite of what it is
    setCheckedProperty(radioButton, !radioButtonIsChecked);

    // you will have to define your own getSiblingsAnswers function
    //  as they relate to your application
    //  but it will be something similar to radioButton.siblings()
    var siblingAnswers = getSiblingAnswers(radioButton);

    uncheckSiblingAnswers(siblingAnswers);
});

function uncheckSiblingAnswers(siblingAnswers) {
    siblingAnswers.each(function() {
        setCheckedProperty($(this), false);
    });
}

function setCheckedProperty(radioButton, checked) {
    radioButton.prop('checked', checked);
    radioButton.attr('data-checked', checked);
}
```

On the page load, set the data-checked property to true or false, depending on whether or not it is already checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
        var radioButton = $(this);
        var radioButtonIsChecked = radioButton.attr('checked') == 'checked';

        setCheckedProperty(radioButton, radioButtonIsChecked);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/304/) hope this myt help:

```
<input type="radio" name="" value="1000" align="middle" id="private_contest">1000 is the value<br>

<input type="radio" name="" value="2000" align="middle" id="private_contest">2000 is the value
```

and relevant jquery is:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {

                $(this).siblings().prop('checked', true);
                $(this).prop('checked', false);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the attribute checked to uncheck, and add the attribute to check the radio button. Do not assign value to it:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" checked>
```

use:

```
$(this).addAttr("checked") 
$(this).removeAttr("checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should never fail, but it's a different approach.
Target the parent, and return which radio IS checked, rather than looking at all of them.
Just an idea

```
var myRadio;
$('#radioParent input:radio').click(function() {
    myRadio = $(this).attr('id');
    //console.log(myRadio);
    //return myRadio;
});
```